# GLFW program closes before main is run

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm writing a program that uses GLFW with MinGW from the command prompt, and the program ends before the first line of the main. What's happening here and how do I fix it?

Here's the code:

```
#define GLFW_DLL
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "first line";

    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "no init";
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "no window";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        std::cout << "draw?";

        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();

        std::cout << "end of loop";
    }

    std::cout << "end";

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with this command:
g++ example.cpp -o example.exe -lgdi32 -lglfw3dll -lopengl32

Comment: Add `\n` or `std::endl` to your `cout` calls. It's possible glfwTerminate is killing your program before the output has flushed.

Comment: adding << std::endl didn't work, I think it's something to do with the static library breaking before the main is called

Comment: It's possible that your DLL are not loaded correctly, try opening the .exe from the file explorer instead of from command line

Comment: Yes! The wrong DLL file was loaded! Must've been from a different version of GLFW.